# WCF. Как задать ограничение "массив не может быть пустым"?

Tags: c#, wcf

Разрабатываю wcf-сервис. 
Метод службы выглядит так
`[ServiceContract]
    public interface IResponsesFromSAPExternalService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendBppProcessingResult( PricesTruItem[] pricesTruList);`

Когда soap ui читает wsdl - я вижу такое:

```
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:pricesTruList>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <enrc:PricesTruItem>
```

Как сделать чтобы pricesTruList стал обязательным, а PricesTruItem имел минимум одно повторение ?

Comment: возможно [статья](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx) будет полезна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно обернуть ваш параметр в класс. После этого вы можете использовать атрибут `DataMember` и указать `IsRequired = true`. Пример:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResponsesFromSAPExternalService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SendBppProcessingResult(ProcessingResult processingResult);
}

[DataContract]
public class ProcessingResult
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public PricesTruItem[] pricesTruList { get; set; }
}
```